# jMeter performance mobile applications - Jmeter don't record

Tags: android, linux, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to make a performance test using JMeter for a stage application using an Android device.
For JMeter I user Templates - Recording[image]

Android:

- the proxy is set on manual, I added the ipv4 address from Desktop ubuntu - setting - network - ipv4 address and I added the port
- I added the CA certificates on Security - settings - credentials - install from storage - apache jmeter...ca[image]

But, when I open/ run the JMeter performance test, nothing is recorded, something needs to be set, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take few more extra steps:

1. Add the next line to the [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) section of your app manifest

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
2. Create `network_security_config.xml` file under your app [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) and put the following code there:

   ```
   <network-security-config>
     <debug-overrides>
       <trust-anchors>
         <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
         <certificates src="user" />
       </trust-anchors>
     </debug-overrides>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
3. Compile your application in [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)
4. Replace the .apk on your device or emulator with the debug version
5. You should be able to record now

More information:

- [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)
- [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording)

Comment: And something else must be added in jmeter after adding xml?

Comment: Nope, on JMeter's side you just need to launch the proxy server

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work